# Check if there exists any non negative integral solution to this equation

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

How to find out if there exists at least one non negative integral solution to the equation  `ax + by = c` in x,y ?

Note that a,b,c are integers in the range [-10<sup>18</sup>,10<sup>18</sup>]

Comment: I added that so people don't give solutions which require iterating over all values of one of the variables. I need an efficient method

Comment: "Negative integral solution"...meaning $\;\Bbb Z\ni x,y>0\;$ ?

Comment: "Non negative" integral solution. x,y >= 0 and x,y are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):
$$
\gcd(a, b) = a x + b y
$$
Unless $\gcd(a, b)$ divides $c$, there is no solution.

All solutions to $a x + b y = \gcd(a, b)$ are given by:
$$
x = x_0 + k \frac{b}{\gcd(a, b)}, y = y_0 - k \frac{a}{\gcd(a, b)}
$$
and $x_0, y_0$ are given by [Euclid's extended algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). This gives an efficient solution to your problem.

Comment: but this does not give non-negative solutions.

Comment: @Anurag, it is easy to see from the given equation if there are positive solutions.

Comment: Does that work for negative values of `a,b`? Can you help as to how to compute `x0 and y0`? So, for the non-negative solutions to occur either of `a` or `b` has to be negative?

Answer (score 1):

The Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ has a solution $(x,y)$ in integers if and only if $d=gcd(a.b)$ divides $c$. Here $a,b,c$ are integers, with $a,b$ nonzero. Note that there is no restriction on the range. If $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution, then all others are given by $(x,y)=(x_0+a/dk,y_0-b/dk)$ with $k$ running over the integers. Now set $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ and see what this means for $k$.

Comment: I need to know whether there is a non-negative integral solution. Not just an integral solution.

Comment: This is easy to see from the formula - see the same answer to the question, which you have accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $c>ab-a-b$ then this equation will always have a non-negative integer solution.